# Merge two columns based on the name of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say, I have this DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame({"a":[["a","aa"],np.nan],"b":[["b","bb"],["bbb"]],"c":[["c","cc"],["c","cc"]],"merge apple":[["d","dd"],["d","dd"]],"merge ball":[["e","ee"],["e","ee"]]})


       a       b      c     merge apple  merge ball
0   [a, aa] [b, bb] [c, cc] [d, dd]     [e, ee]
1   NaN      [bbb]  [c, cc] [d, dd]     [e, ee]
```

I want to merge the column that contains word "apple" to column a, and the column that contains word "ball" to column b. I want the resulting table to be like this.

```
       a               b              c
0   [a, aa, d, dd]  [b, bb, e, ee]  [c, cc]
1   [d, dd]         [bbb, e, ee]    [c, cc]
```

I can't do something like `df['a'] = df['a'].str.cat(df['merge apple'],sep=" ")` or `df["a"] = df["a"] + df["merge apple"]` because I don't have the exact name of the column. Also, I need to append the text in the list.

Comment: So how are you referencing which column to merge if the name of the column is not available? is it by position like Ist column etc?or is it by column which starts with 'a' or 'b' etc?

Comment: Which column to merge with will be decided by the substring contained in a column name. For example, if it contains "apple" merge it to column "a". Of course, this is only an example dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the below using filter function:

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['a','aa'],['a']],'b':[['b','bb'],['bbb']],'c':[['c','cc'],['c','cc']],'merge apple':[['d','dd'],['d','dd']],'merge ball':[['e','ee'],['e','ee']]})

>>> x
         a        b        c merge apple merge ball      combined_a
0  [a, aa]  [b, bb]  [c, cc]     [d, dd]    [e, ee]  [a, aa, d, dd]
1      [a]    [bbb]  [c, cc]     [d, dd]    [e, ee]      [a, d, dd]

>>> y = list(x.columns.values)

>>> merge_columns_with_a = list(filter(lambda x: 'apple' in x, y))

>>> merge_columns_with_a
['merge apple']

>>> for i in merge_columns_with_a:
...     x['a'] += x[i]

>>> x
            a        b        c       merge apple merge ball
0  [a, aa, d, dd]  [b, bb]  [c, cc]     [d, dd]    [e, ee]  
1      [a, d, dd]    [bbb]  [c, cc]     [d, dd]    [e, ee]  

>>> merge_columns_with_b = list(filter(lambda x: 'ball' in x, y))

>>> merge_columns_with_b
['merge ball']

>>> for i in merge_columns_with_b:
...     x['b'] += x[i]

>>> x
            a               b        c       merge apple  merge ball 
0  [a, aa, d, dd]  [b, bb, e, ee]  [c, cc]     [d, dd]    [e, ee]
1      [a, d, dd]    [bbb, e, ee]  [c, cc]     [d, dd]    [e, ee]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) + [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [["a", "aa"], np.nan],
    "b": [["b", "bb"], ["bbb"]],
    "c": [["c", "cc"], ["c", "cc"]],
    "merge apple": [["d", "dd"], ["d", "dd"]],
    "merge ball": [["e", "ee"], ["e", "ee"]]
})

# Stack to long format:
df = df.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()

# Convert all columns to first letter
df['level_1'] = df['level_1'].str.split('merge ').str[-1].str[0]

# Pivot with aggfunc to flatten list of lists (nan safe)
df = df.pivot_table(index='level_0',
                    columns='level_1',
                    values=0,
                    aggfunc=lambda s: s.apply(pd.Series).stack().tolist()) \
    .rename_axis(None) \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
                a               b        c
0  [a, aa, d, dd]  [b, bb, e, ee]  [c, cc]
1         [d, dd]    [bbb, e, ee]  [c, cc]
```